# Table To Dictionary <String,Object> using Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, dictionary, lambda

I am trying to convert data table to dictionary which contains a string and an object, the object is returned through a method

```
public class myObj
    {
        public string Sid { get; set; }
        public string Serial { get; set; }
        public Double RunTime { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string LogonTime { get; set; }
        public string SqlText { get; set; }
        public string Database { get; set; }
        public bool Terminated { get; set; }

        public myObj Obj(DataRow row)
        {

            myObj Session = new myObj();
            myObj.Sid = row["SID"].ToString();
            myObj.Serial = row["SERIAL#"].ToString();
            myObj.Username = row["USERNAME"].ToString();
            myObj.RunTime = Convert.ToDouble(row["RUN_TIME"].ToString());
            myObj.LogonTime = row["LOGON_TIME"].ToString();
            myObj.SqlText =  row["SQL_FULLTEXT"].ToString();
            myObj.Database = row["DATABASE"].ToString();
            return Session ;
        }
    }
```

`Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,myObj >> result = table.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(row => row["USERNAME"].ToString() + "|" + row["SQL_FULLTEXT"].ToString(), row =>` (here I need to reference the Obj(Datarow row) method and pass the row to get the object returned in order to have a dictionary with

I would like to do this through Lambda expression. I was able to do this through looping using Dictionary.Add

Comment: Why isn't the Obj() method static and/or just a constructor method?  Also not sure about the syntax you posted.  I don't see how it could possibly compile since you are setting properties on myObj instead of Session.

Comment: your response helped me solve my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You CAN do this with a Dictionary.Add, but you cannot with ToDictionary.  The reason for this is that ToDictionary does let you change specify a key selector function 'row => row["USERNAME"].ToString() + "|" + row["SQL_FULLTEXT"].ToString()' in your case, but it does **not** allow you to change the underlying enumerable type.

You can only create a dictionary of type Dictionary`<T, DataRow>` (assuming table is of type DataTable) using ToDictionary();

Comment: I was able to implement the solution based on stephen.vakil's response to my question. please check my answer below. I tested it and it worked.

Comment: You asked about creating a Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,myObj >> not a Dictionary<myObj, string>.  But I'm glad to hear you got the issue solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class myObj
    {
        public string Sid { get; set; }
        public string Serial { get; set; }
        public Double RunTime { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string LogonTime { get; set; }
        public string SqlText { get; set; }
        public string Database { get; set; }
        public bool Terminated { get; set; }

        public myObj()
        {
        }
        public myObj(DataRow row)
        {

            myObj Session = new myObj();
            myObj.Sid = row["SID"].ToString();
            myObj.Serial = row["SERIAL#"].ToString();
            myObj.Username = row["USERNAME"].ToString();
            myObj.RunTime = Convert.ToDouble(row["RUN_TIME"].ToString());
            myObj.LogonTime = row["LOGON_TIME"].ToString();
            myObj.SqlText =  row["SQL_FULLTEXT"].ToString();
            myObj.Database = row["DATABASE"].ToString();
            return Session ;
        }
    }

    Dictionary<myObj,string > result =
                    table.AsEnumerable()
                        .ToDictionary(
                            row => new myObj(row), row => row["USERNAME"].ToString() + "|" + row["SQL_FULLTEXT"].ToString());
```